# Run PHP File every 10 minutes?

Tags: php, file, timer, web

Ok first things first, I have looked into cron jobs and I unfortunately only have access to the FTP so unless I have misread it I don't think thats possible.

There is no need for a visual representation, its just the function that is run on the page.

I want it to just run some mysql code and do a quick function..

Looking for any helpful answers or suggestions be it jquery, or some other plugin, thanks!

Comment: You can add a cron task to run wget and get a PHP page from your web server.

Comment: It's called `cronjob` or scheduled task, what platform do you use?

Comment: you should ask the server guy/hosting provider to give you access to cron or at least set it for you. this is your right.

Comment: I am windows, as for the server I couldn't say. Should I contact my hosting provider?

Comment: Ask him if you can schedule a cronjob on your hosting.

Comment: I shall, but is there no other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google for cronjob service and pick one. (first result for me was:[https://www.setcronjob.com](https://www.setcronjob.com/))

set up a page on your server which does the desired action.

feed the url of this page to the cronjob service and let it called every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using an external cronjob service?

You talked about jQuery so I imagined you have a front-end side, add a secret route like `/_/path/to/cron/job` and call it using things like the [Iron.io IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/products/worker)

Comment: Looking into this now, as I don't have access to the SSH for the root other than via FTP, which isn't what I need :/

Comment: You should only need access to the server control panel to set up a cron, SSH is usually only used on dedicated servers and even then they still often have a control panel.

Comment: You don't need the root access.
Look at the samples or the GitHub README : https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_php#readme

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have the access to exec command anyhow, you can do something like this to setup a cron job via PHP script

```
exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n30 9 * * * /path/to/script" | crontab -');
```

If thats not the case, you should see this: 
[Its a third-party cron job service. 10 min interval is available for free.](https://www.setcronjob.com/)